# How to assign a variable using 3 arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to write an add-in for a finite element geology piece of software.

I have three arrays which are essentially a coordinate system. I want to assign a value to a variable depending on its position in the grid system. Basically I want to say if my node is within an x range and a y range, then my aquifer thickness at this node is this value. So far I have this.

```
//create an array of xcoords of data points:
double[] xcoord = new double[11] {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50};

//create an array of ycoords of data points:
double[] ycoord = new double[11] {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50};

//create an array of aquifer thickness

double[] aquiferThicknessPoints = new double[121]
        {
        10, 10, 12, 13, 12, 15, 14, 15, 14, 13, 13,
        10, 10, 13, 15, 16, 14, 13, 15, 16, 12, 13,
        12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 17, 14, 15, 18, 14, 14,
        13, 14, 15, 18, 20, 17, 15, 17, 18, 15, 15,
        14, 15, 17, 18, 21, 17, 18, 18, 19, 17, 16,
        15, 15, 17, 17, 20, 21, 21, 19, 19, 18, 18,
        15, 15, 17, 20, 20, 21, 22, 21, 19, 19, 19,
        16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 22, 21, 20, 20, 20,
        17, 18, 20, 22, 23, 24, 24, 23, 22, 20, 21,
        18, 19, 21, 22, 24, 25, 24, 23, 22, 22, 22,
        19, 19, 22, 22, 24, 25, 25, 23, 23, 22, 23,
        }; 

dataPointSpacingHalf = dataPointSpacing / 2;



for (int i = 0; i < xcoord.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ycoord.Length; j++)
    {
        if (nodeX >= (xcoord[i] - dataPointSpacingHalf) && (nodeX < (xcoord[i] + dataPointSpacingHalf)) && (nodeY >= (ycoord[j] - dataPointSpacingHalf) && (nodeY < (ycoord[j] + dataPointSpacingHalf))))
        {
            aquiferThickness = aquiferThicknessPoints[?];
        }
    }
}
```

I can see how the nested for loops will loop through 110 times, but i don't know how to assign my aquifer thickness from my array to each loop.

I open to any way of solving this problem as I'm very new new to programming and am still not sure which is the best way to achieve things.

Comment: Can you give more data? What does nodeX and aquiferThickness hold?

Comment: We can't answer this question directly, as we don't know the relation of your `x` and `y` coordinates to your `double[110]` (why isn't it a `double[121]` btw?). You should consider to use a two-dimensional array for your thickness, instead of the one-dimensional one, so you could just access it via `aquiferThickness[x][y]`, otherwise, your access would probably be something similar to `aquiferThickness[10 * x + y] = ...`.

Comment: Yes the nodeX and nodeY value are passed from the software and are defined by the mesh properties, so can be any x or y value. The aquiferThickness can be any value i choose.

Comment: Do you need the thickness at the _closest_ known point or an _interpolated value_ between defined grid coordinates? (Please add this information to your question)

Comment: I agree with @LInsoDeTeh. Most likely the best solution is going to be a complete rewrite of how you're attempting to do this, but you don't give nearly enough information for us to accomplish that. Unfortunately, if you did, the question would then be out of scope for the site.

Comment: Yes the double array should be 121. I've updated that now. Each value in the aquifer thickness array corresponds to an x, y value defined by the xcoord and ycoord. So at 0, 0 the aquiferThickness = 10, at 0, 10 aquiferThickness = 12 and so on.

Comment: @DrKroch yea I need to set the thickness at all the nodes between defined grid coordinates.

Comment: The software runs the piece of code at each node. If the coordinate of the node is within the specific range, then I set the aquifer thickness at this node. The aquifer thickness is then used in further calculations, before returning a value back to the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `i * xcoord.Length + j` insted of `?`

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xcoord.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ycoord.Length; j++)
    {
                                                      //Here is the magic!
        //without considering coordinates
        //aquiferThickness[i, j] = aquiferThicknessPoints[i * xcoord.Length + j];

        //considering coordinates
        aquiferThickness[i, j] = 
            aquiferThicknessPoints[
                CoordToIndex(xNode,indexedCoords) * xcoord.Length + 
                CoordToIndex(yNode,indexedCoords)];

    }
}
```

Also to consider the xNode, yNode coordinate, you can take this approach

```
Dictionary<int, double> indexedCoords = new Dictionary<int, double> { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 5 }, { 2, 10 }, .... };

int CoordToIndex(double node, Dictionary<int, double> indexedCoords)
{
    return indexedCoords.First(i => i.Value > node).Key;
}
```

Comment: @Houssein Narimani Rad. Yea the [i * xcoord.Length + j] does the trick perfect. I knew it was something simple. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @GeorgeFrench glad to be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a two-dimensional array for your `aquiferThicknessPoints`:

```
double[,] aquiferThicknessPoints = new double[,]
{
  {10, 10, 12, 13, 12, 15, 14, 15, 14, 13, 13},
  {10, 10, 13, 15, 16, 14, 13, 15, 16, 12, 13},
  {12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 17, 14, 15, 18, 14, 14},
  {13, 14, 15, 18, 20, 17, 15, 17, 18, 15, 15},
  // the rest
};
```

You can then address the data using the two coordinates:

```
aquiferThickness = aquiferThicknessPoints[j, i];
```

(or `i, j`, it's not obvious how your data is organized)